# Comments inside a multi-line list in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to have something like

```
BROKEN_THINGS = \ 
  thing1 \ # thing1 is completely broken
  thing2 \ # thing2 is broken too, see BUG-123
```

Look like this is not possible with [g]make.

I ended up using `warning` function (this works because `$(warning X)` always returns empty string):

```
BROKEN_THINGS = \
  thing1 $(warning "thing1 is completely broken") \
  thing2 $(warning "thing2 is broken too, see BUG-123") \
```

The last is not ideal since warnings garble the output of make (and also `warning` is a gmake-specific).

Is there a better solution to document a long multi-line list of things?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
BROKEN_THINGS =
BROKEN_THINGS += thing1  # thing1 is completely broken
BROKEN_THINGS += thing2  # thing2 is broken too, see BUG-123
```

Comment: Nice, this looks much less fragile!

Comment: You can actually skip that first line and just start with "+=".

Comment: Yes, although if the variable has a value from some other location the first line will clear it out.

Comment: What about `BROKEN_THINGS := thing1 etc`? Ah, looks like I can use += after the initial :=